# Unable to POST data with the Django REST Framework : Not Found

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm trying to figure out why the Django REST Framework throws a 404 Not Found when I POST data with the code below, because when I load the browsable API with the URL it correctly displays the object list with the HTML form to `POST` data.

The Django project that serve the API run in a Docker container as well as the client, but in a separate Docker host.

How could I fix the issue ?

**Server**

Console logs

```
django-1         | Not Found: /api/strategy/target/
django-1         | [26/Sep/2022 14:27:05] "POST /api/strategy/target/ HTTP/1.1" 404 23
```

project/project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/strategy/", include("strategy.urls")),
]
```

strategy/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from strategy.api.views import TargetViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("target", TargetViewSet, basename="targets-list")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

strategy/views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from strategy.api.serializers import TargetSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser


# Create new model
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
class TargetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TargetSerializer
    queryset = Target.objects.all()
```

**Client**

```
res = requests.post("http://1.2.3.4:8001/api/strategy/target/",
                    data=data,
                    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)}
                    )
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the reason of the problem, but it should be regex as router parameter: `router.register(r"target", TargetViewSet, basename="targets-list")`

Comment: Thanks, I did the modification but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.register("target", TargetViewSet, basename="targets-list")
```

The defination of the router is correct but I think the basename you have there is the problem. Since you have a queryset defined in your views, you can remove the basename completely. You only need to use basename if you define your own get_queryset function.

So try this and let's see if it works out for you.

```
router.register("target", TargetViewSet")
```

Comment: Hi, I did the modification but DRF still throws the same error.

Comment: Are you able to make a post via the browsable API?

Comment: Hum, no, it throws the same error. Now i understand where the problem comes from, wow, thanks !! The problem womes from the data I'm trying to insert, one of the Foreignkey ID isn't found.

Comment: So is that all sorted out for you now?

Comment: Yes everything works fine now